# How do I detect the usage of a ContextManager in Python?

Tags: python, refactoring, contextmanager

I am trying to refactor the following:

```py
with MyContext() as ctx:
    ctx.some_function()
```

...into something more like this:

```py
with MyContext():
    some_function()
```

How can I detect in the body of `some_function` that I have called it within the context of `MyContext()`? I would prefer that this is done in a thread-safe way.

This appears to be possible because it is done in the builtin `decimal` module:

```py
from decimal import localcontext

with localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec = 42   # Perform a high precision calculation
    s = calculate_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using [`threading.local`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data) for thread-local data to store contexts:

```py
import threading
from contextlib import contextmanager

thread_local_data = threading.local()


@contextmanager
def MyContext():
    try:
        # every thread has different `ctx` value
        thread_local_data.ctx = "[some context]"
        yield
    finally:
        pass


def some_function():
    print(f"My context is {thread_local_data.ctx}")


with MyContext():
    some_function()
```

Prints:

```
My context is [some context]
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to crawl up the call stack,
looking for evidence of a context manager.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from io import StringIO
import dis
import inspect


class MyManager:
    def __enter__(self) -> None:
        print("enter")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback) -> None:
        print("exit")


def app() -> None:
    with MyManager() as m:
        report_on_ctx_mgr()


def report_on_ctx_mgr() -> None:
    stack = inspect.stack()
    assert "app" == stack[1].function
    fn = globals()[stack[1].function]
    src = inspect.getsource(fn)
    print(list(filter(_contains_with, src.splitlines())))

    out = StringIO()
    dis.dis(fn, file=out)
    disasm = out.getvalue()
    if "MyManager" in disasm:
        print(disasm)


def _contains_with(s: str) -> bool:
    return "with " in s


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

output:

```
['    with MyManager() as m:']
 16           0 RESUME                   0

 17           2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (NULL + MyManager)
...
```